# Rails + Devise: How to make instance for log in accessible for the whole website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise

I have in the navbar link for sign up/in. I am using Devise.

My problem is that I don't know how to set up variable instance, that would be accessible for the whole application (across to all controllers and actions).

For sign up, I did following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :load_registration

  def load_registration
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

Which seems to be working. When I click on the link, then will pop up a window where will be displayed a form for sign up (if the user is not logged in). But how to do the same for log in?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for `current_user` if a user is logged in.  If so, your ApplicationController would change to:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :load_registration

  def load_registration
    @user = current_user || User.new
  end
end
```

This way, if `current_user` is available, `@user` would be set to it, otherwise a new instance of `User` would be set to `@user`.

However, this defeats part of what devise does for you, as you should generally use `current_user` in your app as a helper for who is currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking about but if you want to link to the registration or login page of Devise, you don't need any instance var. It depends on your resource but should be something like:

```
<% unless current_user %> 
  <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %>
  <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>
```

Run `rake routes`to learn about your Devise paths.

If you want to put the login or register forms just in the navbar, you can do it with

`<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`

or

`<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`

And include Devise helpers in your application helpers:

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end
```